# PHP system() - return status is always 0

Tags: php, unix, system, return, status

I need to get the following scripts running.

```
// File: script_a.php
<?php exit(1); ?>

// File: script_b.php
<?php 
     system('php script_a.php', $return);
     var_dump($return);
?>
```

Now my problem: On my windows system running `script_b.php` shows `int(1)` as expected. On our Unix-Server I always get `int(0)`, what makes it impossible for me to check, if a certain failure happens inside the `script_a.php`.

Does anybody knows this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: What does `$?` contain when running script_a.php from the command line?

Comment: What php version are you using on unix server, comparing with windows

Comment: If I run script_b from commandline, everything works fine. What is $?

Comment: The windows system runs on PHP 5.2.6 and the Unix on 5.2.11

Comment: Did you try with a string on both ? like `exit('oopsy')` to see if it still does the same error. If that's the case then, it must be a php ini config to change.

Comment: If I use a string as param on exit, the string is send to the standard output and the return value is still 0.

Comment: `$?` is the return parameter in bash. `php script_a.php ; echo $?`

Comment: How is this script normally called? You said that it works if you run it from the command line.

Comment: What are the return values for each OS if you replace `exit(1)` with `exit(2)`?

Comment: Thx for all your answers. Finally I got the reason for this failure. Actually I was always calling `php script_a.php | tee test.log` to log the output. If I don't do the logging with tee I get the expected result `int(1)`

Comment: The reason for that is that i always get the exit status of the tee command. Any solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if it's calling the right php executable on th Unix machine. On many UNIX systems you would need to call the php-cli executable insted of the php one for use on the command line.
Another thing to check would be permissions. Maybe the user executing the script_b.php script doesn't have permissions to execute script_a?

Answer (score 1):

`__halt_compiler()` is called somewhere , able to check that ?

Comment: @Ignacio - i can replicate the same output when embed `__halt_compiler(); exit(1);`, and possible the PHP in the unix alias to something ?

Comment: Wouldn't it fail on both platforms in that case?

Comment: yup, it has to be failed on both case, but owner only said `php script_a.php` , and the `php` might act differently

Answer (score 1):

Try making the PHP `system` call with the absolute path of both the PHP executable and the script filename, e.g.: `system('/usr/bin/php /path/to/script_a.php', $return);`. Maybe it's a path issue. (You may find the absolute path of your PHP executable with: `which php`).

Also, as someone suggested, try debugging the actual return value of script_a.php on your UNIX server by running `php script_a.php; echo $?` on the command line. That `echo` will output the last return value, i.e., the value returned by script_a.php.

Anyway, I suggest doing an `include` with a `return` statement as described in Example #5 of the [include() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). If you can adapt your scripts like this, it's a more efficient way of communicating them.

```
// File: script_a.php
<?php return 1; ?>

// File: script_b.php
<?php 
     $return = (include 'script_a.php');
     var_dump($return);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if safe_mode is enabled on unix server?

PHP Note:

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you
>   can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical
>   reasons, it is currently not allowed
>   to have .. components in the path to
>   the executable.

Or maybe the system function is forbidden to be executed?

Comment: safe_mode is turned off. And system is allowed to be called. If I put some echo statements in script_a before exiting, I can normally fetch that output, but exit state is still 0.

Comment: have you tried other execute methods? maybe exec() or passthru() works right

Comment: I tried both, exec() and passthru(). On the commandline the result is as expected but execution on the webserver results in $return being 0.

Comment: what if you do a echo 1 instead of exit(1) ? exit with a number just send a exit signal and will not print anything according to php docs, maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it either (PHP 5.3.3, Ubuntu).

When I set the exit-value to something better grep-able, like "666", tracing the scripts returned also what is expected:

```
strace -f php5 script_b.php 2>&1 | grep EXITSTATUS

[pid 18574] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 666}], 0, NULL) = 18575
waitpid(18574, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 666}], 0) = 18574
```

The "-f" to strace let's it follow child processes as you use the system call. "2>&1" redirects stderr to stdout to let everything grep. You can also pipe it to "|less" to go through but the output is long and not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on my system, Ubuntu Hardy.  Here's a sample:

```
/tmp$ mkdir /tmp/sbuzz
/tmp$ cd /tmp/sbuzz
/tmp/sbuzz$ echo '<?php exit(1); ?>' >script_a.php  
/tmp/sbuzz$ cat >script_b.php
<?php 
     system('php script_a.php', $return);
     var_dump($return);
?>
/tmp/sbuzz$ php script_b.php 
int(1)
/tmp/sbuzz$ echo '<?php exit(2); ?>' >script_a.php  
/tmp/sbuzz$ php script_b.php
int(2)
/tmp/sbuzz$
```

Exit code 0 means successful execution of the program, so it kind of sounds like you are perhaps running the wrong script_a.php or perhaps the "php" executable isn't doing what you are expecting?  Perhaps you have a script called "php" that is in your path before the interpreter?  What does "which php" report?  On my system it says "/usr/bin/php".

If PHP can't find the script, it would exit with 1, for example:

```
/tmp/sbuzz$ cat script_b.php 
<?php
     system('php doesnt_exist_script_a.php', $return);
     var_dump($return);
?>
/tmp/sbuzz$ php script_b.php 
Could not open input file: doesnt_exist_script_a.php
int(1)
/tmp/sbuzz$
```

In this case I changed the script_b.php to try to run a script that doesn't exist, and I get the exit code 1 (it should be 2 if it completed successfully, because I changed the script_a above), but it also shows the error that it couldn't run the program.

You might want to try changing it to specifically run the full path to the PHP executable:

```
system('/usr/bin/php script_a.php')
```

or also the full path to the script as well:

```
system('/usr/bin/php /tmp/sbuzz/script_a.php')
```

You could also try specifically executing a program that will return 1, just as another data-point, such as:

```
system('false')
system('bash -c "exit 69"')
```

You might want to try an exit code other than 1, which is a common failure.  That's why I did "exit 69" above.  "false" will exit with 1.

Also, of course, try running the script_a.php directly:

```
/tmp/sbuzz$ php script_a.php 
/tmp/sbuzz$ echo $?
2
/tmp/sbuzz$
```

The "$?" is the exit code of the last run command, at the shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    die(1);
?>
```

If that fails as well, check out the stdout of:

```
strace php script_a.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these problems are related, but you may take a look on [exec always returns -1 (or 127)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459270/exec-always-returns-1) as i had a similar problem in the past... even if i didn't acually solved it.

In your case, it might be another problem, not sure how it would be reproduceable, but i've seen caeses where the return string for an unknown command would be the return string from `bash` (`bash: command not found`). On most servers i dont anything though. You may try and check the shell setup for the current user(i assume it would be www-data)

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration of your comment that your problem is occuring in UNIX system when your script_b is something like

> system('php script_a.php | tee myLogFile', $return);

You may use this syntax

> system("bash -c 'php script_a.php | tee log.txt ; exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]}'", $return);

Do man bash and search for PIPESTATUS for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just had a similar problem.

The exit status was being set to 0 when I had the script run in the background, something like

```
system('php script_a.php &', $return);
```

Could you have been doing that but just generalizing for readability?

Answer (score -1):

you need to be running as root or use sudo to access via php.

try something like this:-

```
system('sudo /usr/bin/php -f script_a.php', $return);
```

in your script_b.php

and edit /etc/sudoers to add the following line:-

```
apache    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php -f script_a.php
```

if php is not in /usr/bin/php change that reference
and also mention the full path of script_a.php file somthing like /var/www/html/script_a.php or path where it is physically located.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you ever need or want to use sudo for a case like this?  this is a security nightmare.  bad, bad, bad, bad, bad idea.

Comment: Please read this link may clear doubts http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch09_:_Linux_Users_and_Sudo